# Dart Analyzer Sources Needing Processing

Tags: dart

I am currently using the Dart Analyzer package to parse and analyze Dart files. Currently it is mostly working with the following code.

```
  PhysicalResourceProvider resourceProvider = PhysicalResourceProvider.INSTANCE;
  DartSdk sdk = new FolderBasedDartSdk(
  resourceProvider, resourceProvider.getFolder('D:\\Dart\\dart-sdk'));

  var resolvers = [
    new DartUriResolver(sdk),
    new ResourceUriResolver(resourceProvider)
  ];

  AnalysisContextImpl context = AnalysisEngine.instance.createAnalysisContext()
  ..sourceFactory = new SourceFactory(resolvers);

  Source source = new FileSource(resourceProvider.getFile(item.path));
  ChangeSet changeSet = new ChangeSet()..addedSource(source);
  context.applyChanges(changeSet);
  LibraryElement libElement = context.computeLibraryElement(source);

  CompilationUnit resolvedUnit =
      context.resolveCompilationUnit(source, libElement);

  var element = resolvedUnit.declaredElement;
```

But this element isn't getting all the information, if it implements or extends classes that are in a different file. I eventually found this

```
 context.sourcesNeedingProcessing
```

Where it shows the additional files that are referenced from the dart file, but it seems like they need processing.

If I copy those existing classes, all into 1 file, I get all the information I need, so I know its particularly about getting these files and processing them into the context.

Comment: Note that `AnalysisContext` is what is being referred to as "task model" here - https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/33546

It will be going away eventually.

Comment: It looks like it's because you're `ChangeSet` only includes the one file, not the imported library that has those classes defined. I don't know enough about `ResourceUriResolver` to know whether it should be able to resolve the URI for the imported file, but I'm guessing it doesn't.

Comment: @NateBosch - unfortunately adding all the other files to the ChangeSet didn't make any difference

Comment: Actually, its part of a project, with a pubspec.yaml. Do I need to add that as well? Or load it somehow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without seeing the code you're trying to analyze I can't be certain, but I suspect that the problem is that you haven't included a URI resolver for `package:` URIs. It isn't necessary to add all of the needed files to the analysis context, you just need to tell it how to find any files referenced from the added files.

Unfortunately, building a resolver for `package:` URIs is non-trivial. You need to create an instance of `PackageMapUriResolver`. That in turn requires using the `package_config` package to create an instance of `Packages`, and then convert that into a map (an example of doing that can be found in `ContextBuilder.convertPackagesToMap`).

That said, if you're using a recent enough version of the package you could use the newer API that we're designing. I believe that what you're trying to do would be achieved by the following code:

```
import 'package:analyzer/dart/analysis/analysis_context.dart';
import 'package:analyzer/dart/analysis/analysis_context_collection.dart';
import 'package:analyzer/dart/analysis/results.dart';
import 'package:analyzer/dart/ast/ast.dart';
import 'package:analyzer/dart/element/element.dart';
import 'package:analyzer/file_system/physical_file_system.dart';

main() async {
  ResolvedUnitResult result = await resolveFile(item.path);
  CompilationUnit resolvedUnit = result.unit;
  CompilationUnitElement element = resolvedUnit.declaredElement;
}

Future<ResolvedUnitResult> resolveFile(String path) async {
  AnalysisContextCollection collection = new AnalysisContextCollection(
    includedPaths: <String>[path],
    resourceProvider: PhysicalResourceProvider.INSTANCE,
  );
  AnalysisContext context = collection.contextFor(path);
  return await context.currentSession.getResolvedUnit(path);
}
```

The collection is able to do all of the work of configuring the contexts for you, simplifying the process of getting analysis results.

A couple of things to note. First, the `AnalysisContext` referenced here is not the same class as the `AnalysisContext` referenced in your sample code.

Second, if you're going to be resolving multiple files then it will potentially be more efficient if you can pass in all of the file paths when creating the `AnalysisContextCollection`.

Comment: Thanks Brian, your answer set me on the right path. I did have to stick with my current code though, because I wasn't sure how to add a PackageMapUriResolver to the new way of doing it. The new way you showed worked, but didn't get package information. I'll post a new answer below, just so you can see what was done.

Comment: @AdamPedley Your changes to your existing code are spot on. The new API assumes that the code being analyzed follows either the conventions documented in `package_config` related to searching for a `.packages` file (but not a `packages` directory) or uses one of the supported build systems (Bazel, Gn, or package:build). It looks like the code you're analyzing doesn't. Most of the tools shipped with the SDK would also fail to find package resolution information the way that code is laid out. I don't know whether you have any control over the layout, but if so you might consider changing it.

Comment: I'm still rather new to Dart. Where is this .packages file meant to be and in what format. I have a pubspec, but its the only place I see that references packages. Is there a link to documentation somewhere?

Comment: When you run `pub` it generates a `.packages` file in the same directory as the `pubspec.yaml` file. You can read more about pub (https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub) and the package file format (https://github.com/lrhn/dep-pkgspec/blob/master/DEP-pkgspec.md#proposal).

Answer (score 1):

I added a PackageMapUriResolver as such

```
var resolvers = [
    new DartUriResolver(sdk),
    new ResourceUriResolver(resourceProvider),
    packageResolver(resourceProvider, 'packageName', resourceProvider.getFolder('C:\\folderLocationOfPackage'))
  ];
```

Then in a separate file I created the packageResolver method.

```
import 'package:analyzer/file_system/file_system.dart';
import 'package:analyzer/source/package_map_resolver.dart';

PackageMapUriResolver packageResolver(
    ResourceProvider provider, String packageName, Folder folder) {
  Map<String, List<Folder>> packageMap = new Map<String, List<Folder>>();
  packageMap.putIfAbsent(packageName, () => [folder]);
  var resolver = new PackageMapUriResolver(provider, packageMap);
  return resolver;
}
```